# How to store cookies values in an Android device using Phonegap and jQuery Mobile?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an app using jQuery1.6.1, Phonegap 1.5(cordova-1.5.0.js), jQuery Mobile 1.0.1, and the cookies plugin (jquery.cookies.2.2.0.js) in Android.

I want to set cookies in one page and want to access the same cookies in another page.

To Set

```
$.cookies.set('sample', 'Cookies_Value');
```

To Get

```
 $.cookies.get('sample');
```

While accessing the app on device, I am unable to set and get the cookies values. Is there any other way to store the cookies in device?

Comment: Will the [CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) solve the problem?

Comment: CookieManager is a java code. But i want to set the cookies using htmls5,Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the same apps in different emulator versions.

I am able to store the cookies in Android 2.2. But its not working on Android 4.0.3.

As per my understand, Latest android version(Android 4.0.3) is not supporting.

Answer (score 2):

It's not reliable to use cookies with PhoneGap/Cordova on Android, so I suggest using **[localStorage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage)** instead.

It's as easy as this:

- Setting a value: `window.localStorage.setItem("sample", "value");`
- Getting a value: `window.localStorage.getItem("sample");`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Phonegap provides the functionality to store cookies.

As you are already using JQuery. You can look at below Plugin.

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

In your first html page after logging in (I presume you have to login)..... using javascript write document.cookie=""; .. it will be passed along each webpage that will be called later..